# How to do cache busting using gulp if require.js is used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, gulp, gulp-buster

I have used gulp-cachebust npm for css cache busting. As I have included css files in html files so it worked. But I m loading js files using require.js. Can I do js files cache busting using gulp. I know we can do it using require.js urlArgs attribute but I want to do using gulp. If we can, which module I have to use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you minifiying/optimizing your RequireJS modules? If so, with what? If not, why not?